# Pass current url to dev tools panel in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get my head around how Chrome developer extensions work.  I want to display the URL of the current active tab in a dev tools panel window.

I've seen examples of doing this:

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;
});
```

Unfortunately I can't figure out where to put this, and how to get the results into the panel.  I never see console.log output from the chrome.devtools.panels.create callback.

Below are the files I've created so far.

manifest.html

```
{
  "name": "DevTools panel",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Dev tools test.",
  "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

devtools.js

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create("DevTools panel","chrome.png", "panel.html", function(panel) { 
    console.log("After panel create");
});
```

panel.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>alert('hello')</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>DevTools panel</h2> 
<div id="currentUrl">The current url should go here</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Embedded code doesn't work on extension pages, use a separate js file.

Answer (score 1):

`chrome.tabs` is not available in the dev tools. You can use the `devtools` API if you're using `devtools_page`:

- https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/devtools_inspectedWindow/#method-eval
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/devtools/inspectedWindow/eval

In Firefox or with the [webextension-polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill):

```js
const [response, error] = await browser.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(
    "location.href"
);

// Your URL is in `response`
```

In Chrome:

```js
chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval("location.href", (response, error) => {
  // Your URL is in `response`
});
```